# Running a thread

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a program which I am attempting to run a process in a separate thread.  Normally I would use Qt for this, but in this particular instance I can't (due to it going on to an embedded device).  My concern is whether or not my current implementation will run the thread correctly, or if it will destroy the thread before processing.  Below is my code:

```
int main(){
  //code
  Processor *x = new Processor;
  //other code
  x->startThread(s);
  //more code which needs to be running seperately
}
```

## Processor.h

```
Class Processor {
public:
  Processor();
  void startThread(std::string s);
  void myCode(std::string s);
  //more stuff
}
```

## Processor.cpp

```
void Processor::startThread(std::string s){
  std::thread(&Processor::startRecording, s).detach();
}

void Processor::myCode(std::string s){
  //lots of code
}
```

Alternatively, if there is an easier way to start `myCode` from the `main` function rather than needing to have the class `startThread`, please let me know.

Comment: What operating system is running on the target device?

Comment: Please read some books (c++ thread and generally using ''new'')

Comment: @DieterLücking No need to be nasty.

Comment: Why not just `std::thread thread (&myCode, s);`? There might be a good reason why you can't do it this way, but if so, your question doesn't say any.

Comment: is startRecording() a static member function ?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - The program will be running on the intel edison (yocto linux)

Comment: @David Schwartz - I am refactoring the code from something that was written for a different platform, and trying to make it easier to update and work with said code.  Originally, the code was written to say 'std::thread (func, arg).detach()'.  Trying to run 'std::thread t(&myCode, s);' from the main loop game me compiler errors when I tried to do so.  It is possible that my implementation was incorrect, but that is what lead to the current implementation (which does compile).

Comment: @Christophe - startRecording is not a static function, though changing that can be done if necessary.

Comment: it is not necessary, but if it's not static, you must provide the object on which it shall be applied as first argument (but in the meantime 865719 has shown this point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you make the thread as a `Processor` attribute.

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e1c597ac908dd22)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

//Processor.h

class Processor {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::thread> _th;
public:
  Processor();
  void startThread(std::string s);
  void joinThread();
  void myCode(std::string s);
  void startRecording(std::string s);
  //more stuff
};

//Processor.cpp

Processor::Processor() {
}

void Processor::startThread(std::string s) {
  _th = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&Processor::startRecording, this, s);  // "this" is the first argument ;)
}

void Processor::joinThread() {
    _th->join();
}

void Processor::myCode(std::string s) {
  //lots of code
}

void Processor::startRecording(std::string s) {
  std::cout << "msg: " << s << std::endl;
}

// main.cpp

int main(){
  //code
  auto x = std::make_unique<Processor>();
  //other code
  x->startThread("hello");
  //more code which needs to be running seperately
  x->joinThread();
}
```

Comment: You probably want just `this` as first argument or `std::ref(*this)`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, it's fixed now.